# How do I use python in sublimetext 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've set up python in sublimetext 3 but can't seem to do anything. It simply returns:

```
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I tried: I have been using spyder but it's too slow. PS: I have anaconda and don't want to use that either.

```
def new_sum(x,y):
    return(x+y)

new_sum(1,2)
```

Comment: Not directly related, but `return` is a statement, so it doesn't need parenthesis to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a value, but you do not print it.

Using the interpreter in interactive mode, if something returns something else than None and isn't placed in a variable, it will be printed. This isn't the case with a script.

It has nothing to do with ST3.

Change `new_sum(1,2)` to `print(new_sum(1,2))`

Comment: Thanks, how do I get such things as working directory? Running `os.getcwd()` doesn't work either. I imported `os`

Comment: This requires a different question I think. Check the os functions.

Comment: Thanks I solved this problem. I'll see how to solve the rest.